# List of rejected computer science papers

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I am developing an algorithm (using deep learning) to automatically review computer science papers and decide if they should be accepted or rejected, and I need a list of rejected papers (including titles and abstract, ideally in csv format), where can I find such a list?

Comment: For machine learning papers, many of the top conferences (e.g., CVPR, NIPS) make the peer review process publicly available -- you could set up a scraper to download the abstracts and preliminary decisions

Comment: will i get the unaccepted papers from this site

Comment: Yes, I suspect so, that's why I mentioned it. Why don't you google around and see what you can find...I don't think you'll find a beautiful CSV with exactly what you want, but if you do the legwork and write a crawler, I bet you could cobble something together. Make sure you check out the terms of use before you start downloading; you could have trouble publishing results from a dataset if you violate the terms of use.

Comment: Why do you need such a list? You can simulate a fake list to test your algorithm

Comment: I am doing project in deep learning model so for training the model i think the fake list will get error in testing phase

Comment: If the negative papers don't work out, another option might be using high-rank journals vs. low-rank journals, or high-citation vs no-citation.

Comment: I wonder whether titles and abstracts provide sufficient information to enable deep learning to accurately rank papers, but it certainly sounds like a nice project. (@cag51 Nice idea!)

Comment: No, but first i'am giving only abstract as my input and i want to add other sections after doing this.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense, what does _automatically rate computer science papers whether to accept or not_ mean?

Comment: @cag51  I just want to get the answer whether to accept or reject the paper

Comment: @user2768 when a paper is given by  checking the vocabulary,grammar, plagarism , the system should detect whether to accept or reject the paper in particular journals

Comment: You should clarify your question.

Comment: sir, I am not having doubt in my project, I just need the unaccepted paper dataset.

Comment: I don't want to explain my full project here, my question is to get the list of unaccepted papers in any journals.

Comment: Papers are rejected on technical grounds or plagiarism, not for spelling or grammar... So you need to check the technical content  - so how do you do that...

Comment: @ammu As I have explained, that list does not exist.

Comment: I vote to reopen. This isn't a shopping question, IMO. Nonetheless, it might be closed on other terms, since the OP doesn't seem able to clarify what they are asking. After many rounds of comments/edits, I think they simply want to know: Do computer science venues publish lists of rejected manuscripts? Which I have already answered https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/127044/22768 Yet, the OP persists in seeking further information, so perhaps that isn't their question

Comment: @SolarMike - I'm also skeptical about this project, but there is more work in this area than I would have thought. Like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08775) paper, which correctly rejects 50% of rejected papers while wrongly rejecting only 0.4% of accepted papers based on running DL on the page layout alone.

Comment: There are a handful of computer science conferences that publish rejected papers (and even their reviews). E.g. [ICLR](https://openreview.net/group?id=ICLR.cc/2019/Conference#rejected-papers) You can scrape data from there.

Comment: I am also voting to reopen. The question is answerable and concerns academia. As a side note, I also don't see a problem with the project. I think you will be surprised how well accept/reject decisions can be guessed based on things like spelling and grammar that shouldn't be so relevant.

Comment: I voted to close (as off topic) - we are not a dataset recommendation service. We could edit the question as @user2768 suggests ("are rejection decisions typically publicly accessible?"), but doing so might "conflict with the author's intent" -- OP pretty clearly just wants a link to a file.

Comment: Now there is a different question after the edit - spelling, grammar etc are no longer mentioned - if the question is changed drastically it then wastes people’s effort who have already answered ...

Comment: @cag51 True, the original question was definitely low effort. I only saw the edited version, which is more reasonable.

Comment: @Thomas Even the edited version stills asks for a list...

Answer (score 4):

> I need [a list of] rejected computer science papers...in csv file format

This information is typically confidential and is not publicly available: Most venues only reveal accepted papers, moreover, committee members and reviewers are generally obliged to keep information gleaned from peer-review private.

Comment: Is there is any way to get such papers

Comment: @user105996 Please read my answer.

Comment: +1 Authors expect their submissions to be kept in **strict** confidence by reviewers / referees / editors / program committees until/unless they are accepted.  I am not aware of **any** computer science conference or journal that publishes lists of rejected papers, nor would I ever submit anything to or review anything for a venue that did publish such a list.

Comment: That said, you **might** be able to arrange for confidential access to (author-blinded) submissions to an ML conference only a few years in the future. All you need to do is convince the conference program/steering committee to approve the experiment _and_ convince authors to give permission for their manuscripts to be included.

Comment: @JeffE You should really provide those comments as an answer. (I suppose you'd need to vote to reopen the question first.)

Comment: @JeffE - as noted in the comments on the question, there are in fact many computer science conferences that make rejected papers and the comments publicly available...e.g., ICLR, which uses openreview.net

Comment: @cag51 I stand corrected!!  My comment should read "**By default** authors expect..."